# Ansible: How to do lookup in a CSV file and populate relevant file contents

Tags: ansible

So the logic I'm looking for is

- Get the list of filenames from a template directory
- Tidy-up filename down to match the format of employeeID from a CSV file
- Check the employeeID in a lookup file (csv file)
- if Found, get the other reference information and populate the template for the employeeID.conf

I've below similar data in a LookupFile

```
EmployeeID,EmployeeName,EmployeeCountry
E123,John,USA
E345,George,UK
...
```

Set of template **filenames**

```
E123.conf.j2
E345.conf.j2
...
```

Each **template** contains (eg E123.conf)

```
{
"id": {{EmployeeID}},
"name": {{EmployeeName}},
"country": {{EmployeeCountry}},
"somethingUnique": "hardcodedValueForEmployee"
}
```

I was able to get logic to populate within the **template**, but comparing with filename is not working.

The coding I've done so far is (but after while registering values, i'm kind stuck). Below is what I've done till now

```
- name: "List templates and get filenames from a huge list of templates"
  find:
      paths: "{{base_dir_template}}"
      patterns: "*.j2"
      file_type: file
  register: emp_usecase_templates

- name: "Derive EmpID from filenames so as to compare it with lookup"
  set_fact: emp_usecase_derived_list="{{item.path | basename | replace('.conf.j2', '')}}"
  with_items: "{{emp_usecase_templates.files}}"
  register: emp_usecase_derived_list_result

- name: "Set Employee variables into template. But not working."
  set_fact:
    EmployeeName: "{{ lookup_file | selectattr('EmployeeID','match',item) | map(attribute='EmployeeName') | list }}"
  with_items: "{{emp_usecase_derived_list_result}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tasks below

```yaml
    - read_csv:
        path: employees.csv
        key: EmployeeID
      register: employees

    - name: List templates and get filenames from a huge list of templates
      find:
        paths: "{{ base_dir_template }}"
        patterns: "*.j2"
        file_type: file
      register: emp_usecase_templates

    - name: Set Employee variables into template
      template:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ my_filename }}"
      loop: "{{ emp_usecase_templates.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
      vars:
        my_template: "{{ item|basename }}"
        my_filename: "{{ (my_template|splitext).0 }}"
        EmployeeID: "{{ my_template.split('.').0 }}"
        EmployeeName: "{{ employees.dict[EmployeeID]['EmployeeName'] }}"
        EmployeeCountry: "{{ employees.dict[EmployeeID]['EmployeeCountry'] }}"
```

created the files

```yaml
shell> cat E123.conf
{
"id": E123,
"name": John,
"country": USA,
"somethingUnique": "hardcodedValueForEmployee"
}

shell> cat E345.conf
{
"id": E345,
"name": George,
"country": UK,
"somethingUnique": "hardcodedValueForEmployee"
}
```

Comment: much appreciated